# How to create user defined variables in ZSH?

Tags: variables, zsh

I need to write a script for running a program with command in terminal with some variables (user defined). Such as;

> ./program VAR1 VAR2 VAR3.

However, my script must be in ZSH since it contains some loops that works well with ZSH. This is the code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env zsh

    set VAR1=$1
    set VAR2=$2
    set VAR3=$3
  
    for ((i = 0; i < 41; i++)); do
    
    ./program.csh $VAR1 $VAR2 $VAR3

    done

    echo program runs!
```

I know that this would work in CSH but I don't know how to convert this to ZSH.
Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: You can't use `set` to set a variable. See for instance [here](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide02.html#l11).

Comment: `set` is csh syntax. It's not used in _any_ shell that takes more strongly after the Bourne/POSIX family. (zsh is not a POSIX shell, but it's more like them than it is like csh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real difference is that `set` is used to set shell options or positional parameters, not ordinary variables.

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

VAR1=$1
VAR2=$2
VAR3=$3

for ((i = 0; i < 41; i++)); do

./program.csh $VAR1 $VAR2 $VAR3

done

echo program runs!
```

You are *really* going to want to become more familiar with `zsh` if you plan on writing scripts in it; this is an extremely basic feature of all POSIX-style shells.

Comment: If you really want to, you can use `typeset` or `declare` in place of `csh` style `set` too. Both work, but `typeset` seems more common in `zsh` scripts. `typeset VAR1=$1` etc.

Comment: @Shawn `typeset` doesn't do anything useful there. Just because `csh` uses a command for variable assignments doesn't mean you need to in `zsh`.

Comment: Yeah, it's not *needed*, but it's perfectly fine to use especially if you're more used to that style.

Comment: There's even less reason to write code in one language with no other purpose than to mimic the idioms and structure of another.